# Integrating Protractor with Yeoman via Grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I want to integrate Protractor with a scaffold produced by Yeoman. I followed a tutorial and therein, the older `scenario-runner` was used for setting up e2e testing (via `grunt`).

I would like to upgrade my scaffold and use Protractor instead.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Adding a config file like protractor's getting started guide says with the location of your spec files and then installing protractor is the way to go. Or you can check linemanjs which is like yeoman and has protractor built-in :)

Comment: For AngularJs yeoman is good i think because it is comeup with build also bt he is using karma for e2e tests and i want to use protractor how can integrate protractor in gruntjs file in yeoman

Answer (score 85):

1. Install `protractor` and `grunt-protractor-runner` from `npm`:

   ```
   npm install protractor grunt-protractor-runner --save-dev
   ```
2. Create a config file for protractor (`protractor.conf.js`), change `specs` and `baseUrl` to your test files and test server:

   ```
   exports.config = {
     seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
     specs: ['test/e2e/*_test.js'],
     baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9001' //default test port with Yeoman
   }
   ```
3. Update your `Gruntfile.js`, add the following after the karma task:

   ```
   protractor: {
     options: {
       keepAlive: true,
       configFile: "protractor.conf.js"
     },
     run: {}
   }
   ```
4. Add the protractor task under test

   ```
   grunt.registerTask('test', [
     'clean:server',
     'concurrent:test',
     'autoprefixer',
     'connect:test',
     'karma',
     'protractor:run'
   ]);
   ```
5. Download and start the selenium server:

   ```
   node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
   node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start
   ```

   (In Windows:)

   ```
   node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
   node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start
   ```
6. Update your `package.json`, add the following after `"devDependencies"`. This will run the command after `npm install` so you don't need to remember every time.

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "install": "node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update"
   }
   ```
7. Run the test using grunt

   ```
   grunt test
   ```

If you want protractor to start the server for you, remove

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
```

from `protractor.conf.js`, then running `grunt test` will start a standalone selenium instance during the test and quit it after running the test suite.

Comment: Checkout Matt Briggs' [grunt-start-webdriver][(https://github.com/mbriggs/grunt-start-webdriver/blob/master/README.md) task.  This grunt task executes `webdriver-manager start`, blocking the grunt build until webdriver is ready to accept connections.

Comment: @SteveJansen Nice, in fact if you don't specify the seleniumAddress option in protractor config file, protractor will start the server automatically if you have ran webdriver-manager update before.

Comment: I also had to add `grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-protractor-runner")` above the `grunt.registerTask`

Comment: It doesn't start Selenium when I remove seleniumAddress.

Comment: @lukas Maybe you can try to follow the answer by AlwaysLearning to add the seleniumServerJar and chromeDriver args

Comment: i had instead exports.config = {
put module.exports = function(config){
and also rewrite configs from karma.conf.js. Instead of spec attribute i used files and it works fine. angular 1.2.6

Comment: `npm install` (step #6) will fail if npm packages are installed with `--production` switch (without devDependencies). One solution is to change install script to `"install": "if [ -f node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager ]; then node node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update; fi;"`. However I don't like it because it is not cross-platform solution. Does anyone have any idea how to change it to be crossplatform, and that `npm install` works when devDependencies are not installed?

Comment: Solved #6 with custom grunt task. To summarize, what the task does:
1. Is cross-platform
2. Won't break build if devDependencies are not installed
3. Is being run during `npm install`

Gist: https://gist.github.com/nikolamilenkovic/fd9aab4d08b5550af4b8

Change package.json to:
`"scripts": { "install": "grunt webdriver-manager:update" }`

Answer (score 10):

One thing to add to the existing answer; if you want to start up the Selenium server automatically you have to also specify the location of your seleniumServerJar and chromeDriver (if using Chrome) like so otherwise the tests will not work until you manually start the Selenium server (make sure to run "webdriver-manager update" from the command line first):

```
protractor: {
        options: {
            keepAlive: false,
            configFile: "test/config/protractor.conf.js",
            noColor: true, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.

            args: {
                seleniumServerJar: 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar',
                chromeDriver: 'node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver.exe'
            }
        },
        run: {

        }
    },
```

Comment: I didn't need to do this in my machine. Maybe is a Windows thing?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Windows and without the above, the server wouldn't start automatically. As soon as this was added, everything was working correctly.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Do you know the file path to the two `args` for a mac?

Comment: I don't, sorry. Hopefully someone else on here does. I'd imagine though that it will be somewhere under your working directory and you could even run fiddler when you run the web driver-manager update to see where the files are downloaded to?

Comment: For mac, the path is fine, but you have to check the files. My version of the jar filename was newer, and you don't have the '.exe' on the chromedriver file.

Answer (score 5):

As [@user2172816](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2172816) mentions in their answer - leaving out `seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'` from your protractor config will usually cause Protractor to start a Selenium instance for you.

**As an alternative, you could use [grunt-protractor-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-protractor-webdriver) to start Selenium:**

1) Install and save **grunt-protractor-webdriver**

```
npm install grunt-protractor-webdriver --save-dev
```

2) Add the following into your Grunt definition function:

```
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-webdriver');
```

3) Add the following example protractor webdriver task:

```
protractor_webdriver: {
        start: {
            options: {
                path: 'node_modules/protractor/bin/',
                command: 'webdriver-manager start'
            }
        }
    }
```

4) Add `protractor_webdriver` to your `test` task before running protractor e.g.

```
grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma',
    'protractor_webdriver',
    'protractor:run'
]);
```