# Install Selenium Server manually to work with Protractor (AngularJS) from Cuba

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

I am developing an AngularJS app, and I like to test it with Protractor (e2e test). I am following [this excelent guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20414770/4908989), but I am stuck in step 5 (Download and start the selenium server), because a live in Cuba and when I try to install the Selenium Server I get a 403 Error (this is for political problems, to not go into details).

And the question is how to install it manually or in another way. Regards, hoping someone can help me.

**Edit:**

When I run `node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update` I get (relevant part):

```
downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/chromedriver_linux64.zip...
Error: Got code 403 from https://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar downloaded to /webapps/webvisor/client/node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar
Error: Got code 403 from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.14/chromedriver_linux64.zip
chromedriver_2.14.zip downloaded to /webapps/webvisor/client/node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver_2.14.zip
```

Comment: This is so painful that they would block you from this kind of activity. Feeling sorry for CUBANS

Comment: You do not know how painful it really is.

Comment: I am SO HAPPY it worked. would you accept the answer then? Also, let's delete the comments to keep it clean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are able to download and install `Protractor` at least. If so, you should be able to run them manually on the console

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

I have a step by step tutorial [here](https://letmedothat.wordpress.com/2014/12/27/pratractor-getting-started/)

Comment: I think @Saifur is referring to [Selenium WebDrivers.](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/)

Comment: You can typically use `FirefoxDriver` or `HtmlUnitDriver` out of the box, so long as you have Firefox installed on the host computer. However, using `ChromeDriver` in your code, for example, requires chrodriver.exe to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a proxy with webdriver-manager (nodejs behind).

Set a proxy (to bypass limitation):

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Then retry to update:

```
webdriver-manager update
webdriver-manager start
```

Another way is to use a VPN to bypass the limitation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I considere it for future related issues. For now, download the driver from another way and put in detinated folder work.