# Automate Protractor / Selenium / Webdriver command

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, selenium, webdriver, protractor

How can i start my localhost server with node app.js, run webdriver-manager start, and protractor conf.js in one command.

Each of these commands take place in a different folder.

I want to streamline this process.

I have a written an alias that executes each command in their respective folders.

Problem is, each of these commands launch a server, and the terminal enters non-canonical mode which causes an issue.

I have tried adding & to the end of each command, but this did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it via a task management tool like `grunt` or `gulp`.

Here is the list of plugins that might be useful in your case:

- [`grunt-protractor-runner`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-runner)
- [`grunt-contrib-connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect)
- [`grunt-contrib-watch`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)

See also:

- [Testing With AngularJS Part 5: Protractor and Grunt](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/java/testing-angularjs-part-5-protractor-grunt/)
- [Integrating Protractor with Yeoman via Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19066747/integrating-protractor-with-yeoman-via-grunt)